# Reflections: анализ модификаторов метода

Tags: java

Мне необходимо выделить из класса `protected`-методы. Я получаю массив `Method[]` из метода `Class.getDeclaredMethods()`, затем анализирую объекты массива. Есть метод `Method.getModifiers()`, который возвращает, как я понимаю, одну из статических констант класса `Modifier`. Прикол в том, что у метода модификаторов может быть несколько (типа `public static`), а у меня в распоряжении только один. Как так то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `getModifiers()` возвращает *битовую маску* — самый простой способ представления множества значений (эдакий `EnumSet` для бедных). Каждый отдельный модификатор в этой битовой маске — это отдельный бит. Например, `public` — самый младший (нулевой) бит, `private` — следующий за ним (первый) и так далее. Чтобы проверять, установлен ли i-й бит в битовой маске, надо проверить на ноль результат операции `(modifiers & (1 << n))`, где `n` — это номер бита. Для упрощения обычно для возможных значений `(1 << n)` заводят подходящие константы, которые как раз есть в классе `Modifier`:

- `Modifier.PUBLIC = 1 << 0 = 1`
- `Modifier.PRIVATE = 1 << 1 = 2`
- `Modifier.PROTECTED = 1 << 2 = 4`

И так далее. Соответственно, чтобы узнать, например, объявлен ли метод `protected`, надо проверить условие `method.getModifiers() & Modifier.PROTECTED != 0`. Именно это и делают вспомогательные статические методы в классе `Modifier`, поэтому можно писать ещё проще: `Modifier.isProtected(method.getModifiers())`.

Answer (score 2):

Ой, тьфу, там есть булевы методы типа `Modifier.isProtected()` и т.п.